# IBMi iDB2 SQL0180 Exception on server but not on local dev machine

Tags: db2

I have been having a trouble debugging an exception that is coming from iDB2,
SQL0180 Syntax of date, time, or timestamp value not valid...

```
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Exception.throwDcException(MpDcErrorInfo mpEI, MPConnection conn)
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command.reportDCError(Int32 rc)
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command.execute()
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at Lincare.Enterprise.Database.DatabaseConnection.GetDataTableUsingCommand() in C:\Users\tassefa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AS400Test\Lincare.Enterprise.Database\DatabaseConnection.cs:line 350
at Lincare.Common.DataAccess.Database.RunStoredProcedure[TTarget](Object parameters, Boolean useIdb2DataReader, Boolean excludeSqlStateAndSQLCodeParams, String storedProcedureName) in C:\Legacy\Assemblies\Lincare.Common.DataAccess\Database.cs:line 181
at Lincare.CustomerAccountNotes.Application.NoteManager.SearchNotes(NotesSearchDto notesSearch) in C:\Legacy\Lincare.CenterUtilities\Assemblies\Lincare.CustomerAccountNotes.Application\NoteManager.cs:line 109
at Lincare.Api.CustomerAccountNotes.Controllers.NotesController.Search(NotesSearchDto notesSearch) in C:\Legacy\Lincare.CenterUtilities\Services\Lincare.Api.CustomerAccountNotes\Controllers\NotesController.cs:line 48
```

The problem is that I can never get that exception on my local machine. I tested the service with the same exact parameter, it works on my local machine but not on the dev machine.

- The problem shows up whenever we try to filter with date fields.
- Yes, I am using the same connection config file for both machines.
- I also checked date formatting string for the stored procedures parameters, they are identical.
- All the parameters passed to the database from both machines are exactly the same.
- I checked the ODBC driver on both machines to check if they have the same version of Client Access, and they do (13.0.10.0).

It seems the database is behaving differently for my machine and the server. Anyone encountered such a problem? Please let me know.

Comment: your  JDBC settings for date is not same on server i think

Comment: I found the issue but it does not explain why it is working on my machine and not on the dev server. I used TIMESTAMP (10) as a parameter type. That works fine on my machine but it blows up in the server.

Comment: mau by try to use string with format '2016-10-26-21.10.30.820'

Comment: I am already formating the date as "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff" which looks like your example but with extra 3 zeros. Anyway it's works now. May be some day when I have the time, I will check to see why my pc and the server are behaving differently.